# Blender 2.8 API - grid_scale?

Tags: versions

in v2.79 the following works:

```
bpy.context.space_data.grid_scale = 0.25
bpy.ops.view3d.snap_selected_to_grid()
```

but v2.8 doesn't know `bpy.context.space_data.grid_scale`

What is the equivalent command in v2.8?

many thanks,
 Smooth

Answer (score 0):

In v2.81 I am changing it like this:

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces.active.overlay.grid_scale = 0.25
```